# How to: call an exe from kernel mode and get back boolean result

Tags: windows, ipc, driver

I want call an **exe with 2 parameters from a kernel mode driver and get back boolean (0 or 1 )result** in the driver .
Is it possible ?
Any API for it .

Comment: I shouldn't think so; what context would the executable be launched in?  But you could write a helper service and have it communicate with the driver via custom IO controls (DeviceIoControl).

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible - there are no documented ways to do this.